# Creating a new column using certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like so:

```
   Year   RS   Team  RS_target
1  1962   599  WSA
2  1962   774  STL
3  1963   747  WSA
4  1963   725  STL
5  1964   702  WSA
6  1964   800  STL
```

I'd like to create a new column (RS_target) that will have the RS value for the next year (i.e. index 1: Year = 1962, RS = 599, RS_target = 747). The aim is to get next year's RS for the team and place that value in the new column "RS_target".

I've been trying a combination of conditionals and apply(), but having trouble getting the output I want. Looking for an efficient alternative method, or any other way to get the desired outcome. Thanks!

Comment: There are two year 1963, how do you know which one to choose?

Comment: @RafaelC I think it's based on Team.

Comment: @RafaelC  there are two separate teams for each year (1962 - WSA, 1962 - STL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first apply `dataframe.groupby()` on `Team` column and then use `shift()` to get next RS value for the Team.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[1962,1962,1963,1963,1964,1964], 'RS':[599,774,747,725,702,800], 'Team':['WSA','STL','WSA','STL','WSA','STL']})


df['RS_Target'] = df.groupby('Team')['RS'].shift(-1)

print(df)

Output:

   Year   RS Team  RS_Target
0  1962  599  WSA      747.0
1  1962  774  STL      725.0
2  1963  747  WSA      702.0
3  1963  725  STL      800.0
4  1964  702  WSA        NaN
5  1964  800  STL        NaN
```

**EDIT**:

If your Year column contains random values b. Sort the column using below before applying `groupby` operation:

```
df.sort_values(['Year'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Just notice that assumes years are sorted